# Conditions on lim sup and lim inf of a sequence for the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $p_n$ be a sequence such that $p_n \to +\infty$ and $0 < \liminf \left(p_{n+1}-p_n \right) \le \limsup \left(p_{n+1}-p_n \right)< +\infty$. What must be the upper and lower limits of the sequence $(q_n)$ such that the series $$\sum\left({1\over{p_n}}\right)^{q_n}$$converge or diverge?

I **can** show that if $\liminf q_n > 1$ the series converges and if $\limsup q_n<1$ the series diverges (also we may assume that $\liminf q_n \ge0$ for otherwise there exists infinitely many values of $n$ for which $q_n$ is negative and thus the sum will contain infinitely many positive numbers all greater than $1$ for example (since $p_n$ goes to $+\infty$) and the series diverges). I have trouble understanding what happens in the other cases. I started with $q_n$ having limit $1$. For example if $q_n = 1$ and $p_n = n$ then the series diverges; are there choices of $p_n$ and $q_n$ (with $q_n \to 1$) such that the resulting series converges?

Comment: For such an example, you can take $p_n=n$ and $q_n=1+2\frac{\log \log n}{\log n}$

Comment: that gives the series $\sum \frac{1}{{n(\log n)^2}}$ right?

Comment: @Kelenner can you suggest something for the other cases too?

Comment: yes, this series $\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$ is convergent.

Comment: @Kelenner With $p_n  = n$, for example $q_n = 2 + \frac{\ln n}{n}$ for $n$ not of the form $k^4$ and $q_n = 1/2$ otherwise?